# inserting values to table from select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO site_city_address (`cityName`, `cityCode`, `stateId`) VALUES  (SELECT a.city, a.cityCode,  b.stateId
  FROM site_address_dropdown a INNER JOIN site_state_address b
    ON a.state = b.stateName);
```

I know it's possibly wrong. What I want to do is to insert the values of a.city, a.cityCode, and b.stateId as cityName, cityCode, and stateId into the shopious_city_address.
How do I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `values` or `select` after an `insert`.  In your case, omit `values`:

```
INSERT  INTO site_city_address
        (`cityName`, `cityCode`, `stateId`) 
SELECT  a.city, a.cityCode, b.stateId
FROM    site_address_dropdown a 
INNER JOIN 
        site_state_address b
ON      a.state = b.stateName;
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `VALUES` keyword. `INSERT INTO...SELECT` has the following syntax,

```
INSERT INTO site_city_address (cityName, cityCode, stateId) 
SELECT  a.city, a.cityCode, b.stateId
FROM    site_address_dropdown a 
        INNER JOIN site_state_address b
            ON a.state = b.stateName
```